# Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql

I try to connect to the MySQL database on my Mac. This MySQL was installed with MAMP. When using phpMyAdmin and the CLI, I can connect to the database. But when I tried to connect by Java, this error happens:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4732)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1340)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2506)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at Hello.main(Hello.java:11)
```

Here is my java code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            //String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/xinandasai?user=root&password=root&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=8859_1";
            //Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xinandasai","admin","cosmo");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/xinandasai?" + "user=admin&password=cosmo");
            //Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            //statement.execute("INSERT INTO test (user) VALUES ('"+user+"')");
            //conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked the Configuration. And I'm sure about these issues:

1. The username and the password is correct because they are correct when using CLI.
2. All privileges are granted by using the SQL sentence: "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'cosmo' WITH GRANT OPTION;"

How can I fix this?

May it be relative with the versions? My MySQL version is 5.5.25. And the connector version is 5.1.30

Comment: @JqueryLearner Unfortunately this method failed too. The same exception was raised.

Comment: I installed an entire version of MySQL Community Edition and run it on port 3307 (different from port 3306 of the MySQL already exists). And I succeeded to connect to the newer MySQL with the same program. So I think this problem comes from some limits made by MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anything wrong in this code. The general syntax is

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
conn.close();
```

I could see that you have tried this combination in the commented string but try replacing localhost with an ip may be that will work. You could get your machin ip via command prompt using ipconfig command

```
Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xinandasai","admin","cosmo");
```

Before that you have to grant access to all ip like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO db_user @'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_passwd';
```

% is the wildcard for an ip address

Comment: I have tried "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'cosmo';" and connect with the address 127.0.0.1. But still useless.

Comment: That is weird. Try resetting the password. Follow this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Comment: I'm using MAMP(Apache+MySQL+PHP for Mac) instead of MySQL for Linux. So I changed the password in GUI. But still useless.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, It is not relative to the Connector version. I've tried same code with versions 5.1.30 and 5.1.13 and worked both.
I also tried the two overloaded methods  :

```
c = DriverManager.getConnection(URL+DBNAME, LOGIN, PASSWORD);
```

and

```
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/universite?" + "user=root&password=root");
```

worked for both versions

Try to be sure that you have the access garanteed to all ip adresses.

Comment: I have tried "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'cosmo';" and connect with the address 127.0.0.1. But still useless.

Comment: Are you running your java app in the same machine as your database machine?

Comment: Yes, both are running on my personal Mac